# Change "Departed" to "User Removed" on our election page for a former moderator with a deleted account

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, user-accounts

Our [election page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/election) uses the following image for a former moderator whose account is now is now deleted:

[image: Departed]

Based on [Change the way deleted users are shown in the Community Moderator Elections page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342694/change-the-way-deleted-users-are-shown-in-the-community-moderator-elections-page) this image was supposed to have been changed to:

[image: User Removed]

However changing the images was a manual process and the image for this deleted user appears to have been missed.   Can it be taken care of now?

Comment: Stephen, where is a list of current moderators?

Comment: Found it https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: Has staff been made aware of this yet? If not, I can probably get the ball rolling.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister A staff member just changed the status to "planned"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The election graphic has been changed. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Answer (score 3):

Goodness. I saw this on the election page and mistakenly thought the former moderator had passed away. The new image is much more clear.

Let's get it done.

Comment: Congratulations Maximillian!